# How to change the date format in a drop down menu

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sessionquery = "
SELECT SessionDate
FROM Session
";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionDate);  



$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $dbSessionDate) . PHP_EOL;  
}
```

Above I have a drop down menu where it displays a Session's Date. At the moment the date is formatted so it looks like this:

```
2012-03-23
```

I want it to be formatted as below:

```
23-03-2012
```

How can I change the date format in the drop down menu?

Comment: [`DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Don't know why you want to change it.  YYYY-MM-DD is the clearest, least ambiguous format.  If you're going to switch to something else, I'd at least use the month name instead of a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $sessionquery = "
SELECT SessionDate
FROM Session
";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionDate);  



$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           

while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) {
    //$sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $dbSessionDate) . PHP_EOL;
    $sessionHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", date("d-m-Y",strtotime($dbSessionDate)) . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know more about this but on my basic knowledge i would suggest this types of date formatte

You canget this code on w3school website it is very helpful for all language.